# Need assistance with Regex for formatting telephone numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need a C# Regex pattern to find telephone numbers in a string and reformat them.

The telephone numbers could be in any format, eg 00 0000 0000 or (00) 0000 0000 or +00 0 0000 0000 or 0000 0000 or 00-0000-0000 or similar formats. So I am basically looking for at least 8 characters of 0-9, plus, minus, space or brackets, up to 20 characters max. This string will only contain phone number(s) and a bit of text so there will be no problem with any other numbers.

I want to replace the numbers found with a hyperlink to that telephone number like the example below with the non-numbers stripped out of the A tag.

```
<a href="tel:0000000000">00 0000 0000</a>
```

This is the code I came up with myself which almost works:

```
string regex = @"(\b[0-9+\(][\(\)0-9 +-]{6,20}[0-9]\b)";
Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
litTelephone.Text = r.Replace(faculty.Telephone, "<a href=\"tel:$1\">$1</a>");
```

It works with many numbers except it doesn't pick up this example **+00 0 0000 0000** if it is at the start of the string (it drops off the leading plus). It also doesn't remove the non-numbers from the A tag.

I don't know why I am so crap at regular expressions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex, keeping exclusively a match if it is following a ''greater than'' (>) will allow you to exclude the number that you want to change:

`(?<=>)[\+]?(\b[0-9+\(][\(\)0-9 +-]{6,20}[0-9]\b)`

Something similar to this would also handles extension:

`(?<=>)([\+0-9]{1,3}([ \.\-])?)?([\(]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)])?([0-9A-Z \.\-]{1,32})((x|ext|extension)?[0-9]{1,4}?)`

Sorry to excessively edit my answer.

Comment: But in my humble opinion, using Regex for this is funny, but risky. If the left part needs to be exactly like the right part, why not just using a cut and past method? With Regex, you can end up with strange errors, which will look unprofessional.

Answer (score -2):

How are you going to handle the countries where people put in extra digits that are not dialed. One example is the UK where +44 (0)20 7451 8123 is dialed as +442074518123. The (0) is not dialled unless you are in the UK in which case you don't dial the +44 and instead dial 02074518123.

Similarly in Russia and other ex-USSR countries you may see numbers beginning with 8 where you do not dial the 8 unless you are both in the same country and not in the same city.

Best to forget regexes entirely. Parse the numbers, applying local rules to strip out digits like I mentioned, then format them by applying the country rules for formatting so that you correctly display these three UK numbers:

```
+44 20 8123 7451
+44 1245 261 766
+44 7825 23 45 67
```

The last one is a mobile phone number which requires you to recognize that it has a mobile dialing prefix.

Of course if you are in a single country, just throw away anything that is not a digit, and then check the first few digits for international or long distance dialing codes, and normalize those to +country-code. The regex for "not a digit" is `[^0123456789]*`

Comment: I believe that the OP's question is how to get all the input phone numbers into ISO form. The only way that regexes could posibly work is with a database of regexes, one per country. Much easier to write a parser that applies country rules only for the hardest parts.

Comment: more than one per country. Enough udiots in every country having their own formatting, sadly.

Comment: I don't have to worry too much about different formats as this field contains only Australian telephone numbers (one or more) and usually just a little bit of text. It is only editted by authorised people and so the content is well controlled, but we do allow for phone number to be in any format they desire.